# extended row selection by n column in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

It is confusing me because normally I will use number for column, however, for this case, I have to use letter for column.

For example, `T1` and now I would like to extended by n column.

- `n = 10`, then range is `T1:T11`
- `n = 20`, then range is `T1:T22`

It is column then I can use .resize, what method I can use instead of resize to get what I would like to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  To resize columns, this should work:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("t1:t11")
rng.Resize(, 10).Select
```

If you're trying to do rows, this seems to work on my test sheet:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("t1:t11")
rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count + 10, 1).Select
```

A third way I've interpreted your question:

```
Dim RowCounter As Long
RowCounter = 20
Range("T1:T" & RowCounter + 1).Select
```

Here's another way:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim RowExtend As Long

RowExtend = 20

Set rng = Sheet1.Range("t1")
rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count + RowExtend, 1).Select
```

Hopefully one of these four ways gets you close.  If not, please clarify your question and I"ll keep hacking away at it.

Answer (score 0):

How about extending the current selection to LEFT ?
Ex: current selection is E10:E100 and I would need to extend the selection to the left with 2 columns, to C10:E100 ?